# Reinstalling gallium drivers after downgrading

Tags: ati, gallium

I am running ubuntu 13.04. I tried foolishly to install the legacy ATI drivers on my machine from some repository. I think I managed to remove them but now I am running only on vesa.

Does anyone have an idea how I can change my configuration such that X uses the Gallium driver again?

package list is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6076883 and `Xorg.0.log here`http://paste.ubuntu.com/6076902

```
sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV610 [Radeon HD 2400 PRO] [1002:94c3]
    Subsystem: Dell Radeon HD 2400 Pro [1028:0302]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. WL-138G v2 / WL-138gE / WL-100gE [1043:100f]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

**Update:** Ubuntu starts still into vesa after purging left over fglrx packages on the system and reinstalling the packages suggested. An xorg.conf is not automatically generated also not by a dpkg-reconfigure. I tried a sudo X -configure but the file created does not improve the situation. I can stop the service lightdm, then load the radeon module, start lightdm again and have then the desired result that the Gallium driver is used and working. However, of course that doesn't change the startup behavior. The current Xorg.0.log can be found here http://paste.ubuntu.com/6080770/

`cat /proc/cmdline` gives:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-30-generic root=UUID=e8b7c26b-537f-486c-b0f5-674f28c5bac0 ro quiet splash
```

Contents of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`:

```
10-evdev.conf             50-synaptics.conf  51-synaptics-quirks.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf      50-vmmouse.conf
11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  50-wacom.conf
```

**Update**: Problem was solved after deleting /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx.conf . This file prevented the right driver from getting loaded. Somehow this was not deleted earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to reinstall almost every package and purge the ones still installed:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove fglrx*
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-radeon libdrm-radeon1 xserver-xorg-video-ati firmware-linux
```

Note from the asker:

Seems that the purge command don't remove effectively all files, hence a extra command is required:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx.conf
```

That should bring the ol' good drivers again.

The important lines from the Xorg.0.log are:

```
[    17.678] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    17.678] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[    17.697] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so: undefined symbol: noXFree86DRIExtension
[    17.697] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
[    17.697] (II) Unloading fglrx
[    17.697] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (loader failed, 7)
[    17.697] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    17.698] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[    17.698] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[    17.698] (II) Unloading ati
[    17.698] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
```